# What is the form of Boltzmann Transport equation (Stosszahlansatz)?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I want to know if it includes integral over momentum of particle under consideration itself. Following [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_equation#The_collision_term_(Stosszahlansatz)_and_molecular_chaos), there is an integral over particle $A$,
$$
\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\right)_\text{coll}=\int\int gI\left(g,\,\Omega\right)\left[f\left(\mathbf p_A',\,t\right)f\left(\mathbf p_B',\,t\right)-f\left(\mathbf p_A,\,t\right)f\left(\mathbf p_B,\,t\right)\right]\,\mathrm d\Omega\,\mathrm d^3\mathbf p_A\,\mathrm d^3\mathbf p_B
$$
where $\mathbf p_i$ is the momentum of particle $i$ before the collision and $\mathbf p_i'$ the momentum after.

This seems to be wrong. But since I am just starting in the field I am not sure. Can someone correct me? If possible, can you give me its connection to collision terms of Boltzmann equation?

Comment: Could you include the integral you are confused about in your question? It would make things clearer and easier. You can use [MathJax](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to format equations

Comment: Hi Gautham, I believe I've copied the right integral over from the Wikipedia entry. If it's not it, please edit your post to correct this.

Comment: @KyleKanos Thank you very much. That is the correct equation.

Comment: @BySymmetry The required integral is now included (thanks to @KyleKanos).